# Help with Linksys WUSB54AG adapter 64-bit drivers

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, 64-bit, network-adapter

So it seems that Linksys doesn't provide 64-bit drivers for their adapters. Is there anyway to get it working without having to install a 32 bit OS?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the actual internal hardware it may work with Prism or RALink drivers, I would poke around and try some.
[This](http://ralink.rapla.net/) shows that you may have the RT2500 chipset.  Google for RT2500 64 bit driver and try them out.
Also, [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/28716-wireless-adapter-64-bit.html#post306174) are some instructions for installing RALink drivers on 64bit Win 7 with your chipset.

Comment: Could you provide some links or some more info to help me find which driver I would need? Thanks :)

Comment: See edit (blah blah 15 characters)

Comment: Where's the download links?